# Magento 2: Force block to be cached

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, block-cache

I've a mega menu extension which I feel is quite slow. It seems to add about 2 seconds on load time for each page.

As this menu does not change between pages I was wondering how to cache a block? I want it generated just once on the first-page load after a cache flush so that each page can just load the cached block rather than having to repeat for each page on site.

The pages are cached and am not talking about the **FPC** here as page load is fine when cached but over **15,000** odd pages warming up a cache will save roughly **30,000 seconds** if this is not repeated constantly.

Comment: Can i ask which megamenu extension it is as you will need to include caching in the extension

Comment: Its called Ves MegaMenu i bought it from Landofcoder but comes up as from Venus Theme in admin.

Comment: You would need to get it rewritten to include caching i have a mega menu extension which i will be uploading publicly in the next few days i am just implementing caching

Comment: Yeah i will take a look is it a free one? It seems to have suddenly sped up a bit but want it cached really am quite interested in rewriting it just never worked with the cache was hoping for a nudge in right direction.

Comment: Yes its free id suggest putting your site through cloud flair if your thinking about speed as this will cache your site with its inbuilt tools

Comment: I shall take a look. Not had much luck figuring out how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think every block cache in magento,

But if you want to increase `cachelifetime` of particular block

You can do from your extension's block

go to your block and write below method

this method already there in `Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock`

```
protected function getCacheLifetime()
{
    return 84600; // for one day you can increase or decrease this num as per your req
}
```

The cache lifetime can also be set like so within construct:

```
 $this->setCacheLifetime(846000);
```

Comment: I'm not sure they are the profiler shows app/code/Ves/Megamenu/view/frontend/templates/topmenu.phtml 1.898545 for the time this goes up and down but surely would be quicker if this was cached?

Comment: in phtml do `echo $block->getCacheLifetime()` this will return false or some int value(if its cached)

Comment: It didn't return anything in this case.

Comment: Means it return false create this method in your block and set time for caching

Comment: It still shows false with getCacheLifetime set in block

Comment: check this article http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/public-content.html

Comment: Thanks but the full page cache will only cache block with that page? I want the block to be cached.

Comment: if you set `cachlifetime=false` in your layout then also your block ignor from caching just like this`<block class="Magento\Paypal\Block\Payflow\Link\Iframe" template="payflowlink/redirect.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
`

Comment: Yeah i know about that but that is disabling cache? Cacheable="true" would be more appropriate here but this does not do what i want.

Comment: I am telling you find this kind of code which disable the cache , and remove that false and set true and check

Comment: ahhh right yeah there is no such code in layouts

Comment: Your main issue is you are getting cachelifetime false means from somewhere it set false , so you need to identify that and revert that

Comment: Ok i will have a look around this code a bit more

Comment: I set the cache lifetime in construct this seems to have fixed the issue however have not tested on main site

Comment: Ok test and let me know and if my answer help you anyway then mark as accepted so others who face same problem can take benefit from this

Comment: Well i would maybe add the cache lifetime in construct to your answer as this is what actually helped.#

Comment: Ok You can edit my answer

Comment: isn't this essentially, no offence, ineffective because it's still subject to FPC?